# SQL Query export para excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, query, razor

Boas,

Estou com algumas dificuldades no resultado de uma query. Para vos enquadradar é o seguinte, eu tenho uma aplicação de registo de "indisponibilidades." e necessito do seguinte:

Todos os dias tenho de extrair um relatório do dia anterior, no entanto esse relatório tem de ter as seguintes condições:

- Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que se encontrem no estado "Aberto". (Aqui tenho de apresentar)
- Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que tenham sido abertas nesse dia (por ex: 15/09/2014)
- Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que tenham sido fechadas nesse dia (por ex: 15/09/2014), no entanto neste ponto pode acontecer o seguinte:

  Uma "indisponibilidade" pode ter sido fechada ontem (15/09/2014) mas ter sido aberta dia (20/03/2014) mas este ponto a query que tenho está a funcionar bem. A minha dificuldade está a acontecer quando uma das "indisponibilidades" ainda não foi fechada e o campo "dataFim" se encontra a null.

As querys que tentei foram:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO' OR dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' OR dataFim = '" + dataFim + "' ";
```

Esta funciona mas está a extrair tambem resultados que tenham sido inseridos hoje (16/09/2014) e o que o campo dataFim se encontra a null.

Tentei tambem:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO' OR dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' OR dataFim = '" + dataFim + "' dataFim is not null; ";
```

No entanto ele faz-me export tambem de todos os que já tenham sido fechadas durante o dia de hoje (16/09/2014).

Alguma ideia ?

Comment: Fiquei com uma dúvida: Você precisa de todas as indisponibilidades que estão abertas E todas as que foram abertas no dia E todas que foram fechadas no dia ou então você precisa de todas as indisponibilidades que foram abertas no dia e que ainda estão abertas E todas as que foram fechadas no dia?

Comment: Preciso de de todas as indisponibilidades que estão abertas E todas as que foram abertas no dia E todas que foram fechadas no dia

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na realidade a condição "ABERTO" deve recair sobre todas as demais.
Ou seja:

```
// Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que se encontrem no estado "Aberto". (Aqui tenho de apresentar)
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades
WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO';"; // independente de data de início e fim

// Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que tenham sido abertas nesse dia (por ex: 15/09/2014)
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades
WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO'
AND (dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' OR dataInicio IS NULL);";

// Apresentar todas as "indisponibilidades" que tenham sido fechadas nesse dia (por ex: 15/09/2014) ou que dataFim esteja NULL:
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades 
WHERE estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO'
AND (dataFim = '" + dataFim + "' OR dataFim IS NULL);";

// Se você quiser utilizar a mesma query para todas as possibilidades precisará de algo como:
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE 
estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO'
AND (dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' OR " + dataPedido + " = 0) -- note que aqui o parâmetro vem "0", ou seja, não informei uma data de pedido
AND (dataFim = '" + dataFim + "' OR dataFim IS NULL OR " + dataFim + " = 0);";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você necessita dividir os filtros colocando parênteses e AND.

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE 
            estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO' OR 
            (dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' AND dataFim = '" + dataFim + "') OR
            (dataInicio = '" + dataPedido + "' AND dataFim is not null); ";
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que seja isso:

```
var query = "SELECT * FROM indisponibilidades WHERE 
        estadoIndisponibilidade = 'ABERTO'  /* todas em aberto*/
        OR  (dataInicio = '" + dataPedido "')   /* todas que foram abertas no dia */
        OR  (dataFim = '" + dataFim ); "; /* todas que foram fechadas no dia */
```

Conforme o @Luidy disse, é sempre bom usar parênteses para facilitar a leitura e o seu próprio entendimento.
Pense que amanhã ou depois, poderá ser necessário fazer uma alteração na query, e pode ser que não seja você que irá fazer.